# Design Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to my app in difirent devices  first device is 4.0 inch screnn and second device is 5.55 inch  when ı apply first device(4.0inch) my app is running very well but in second device(5.55 inch) screen is stretched.
My question is how can ı design all devices?

First Device 4.0 inch

[image]

Second Device 5.55 inch
the following I draw red arrow 
[image]

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="İzmir Üniversitesi Mobile"
        android:textColor="#EADCCA"
        android:textSize="22sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:alpha="0.50" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" >

            //ÖBS
             <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Öğrenci Bilgi Sistemi" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_obs"
         />

    //DERS PROGRAMI

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ders Programı" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dersp" />

      //Akademik Takvim
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Akademik Takvim" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

       <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_takvim" />

       //İletişim
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="İletişim" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_iletisim" />

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yemekhanede Bugün" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_yemek" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" >

            <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="Haberler ve Duyurular" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

      <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_haber" />

      //Kişisel İşlemler

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kişisel İşlemlerim" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_kisisel" />

        //Ögrenci Web Mail

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Öğrenci Web Mail" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mesaj" />

        //Online Dersler

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Online Dersler" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_online" />

        //Ayarlar

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ayarlar" 
        android:textSize="9dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ayar" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: please, attach your layout xml

Comment: You didn't write what exactly is wrong / how do you want it to look. The easiest may be to center the menu inside the semi transparent black box, is that what you want?

Comment: Just a suggestion. If you test it on smaller screen you might even don't see your bottom too options. You can even test this in Android Studio Layout/Design without phone. If you want to show all items, then test on different screens and adjust item sizes else put all in a Scroll view. Also, like mentioned in answer, set parent view center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a guide for designing for multiple screens: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

If you read the guide, you will see that for the scenario you describe, both 4 vs 5.55 inches belong to the same layout folder (large) so there's no solution in there. However, you need to read it if you target other screen sizes as well (e.g. Tablets).

To answer your question, one thing you can do is to set the shadow box height to "wrap_content" so it is not stretched and then set its gravity to center.

I could give code snippets if I had your layout xml file.

### Edit: Updated with code

1) I would totally remove this View element:

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/view1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="#000000"
     android:alpha="0.50" />
```

2) I would add these two lines to the Linear Layout that follows the removed View

```
android:background="#000000"
android:alpha="0.50"
```

3) I would add the following line to the Frame Layout that is before the removed View

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

4) I would position the TextView textView1 above the Frame Layout

Comment: thank u for answer but ı'm new in android I ll try to Multiple screens @Thanos